# node.js observer race conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I was reading the node.js API documentation, a phrase immediately came to mind: "race condition".  For example, here's how you're meant to handle streamed file reading in node.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var rr = fs.createReadStream('foo.txt');
rr.on('readable', () => {
  console.log('readable:', rr.read());
});
rr.on('end', () => {
  console.log('end');
});
```

But what happens if the `readable` event is fired before the `rr.on('readable'...` function is executed?  Won't that observer miss the event and fail to read the data?  This observer pattern is all over the place in node.js so I'm guessing there's some built-in way to stop the race condition, but what is it?

Comment: @bergi It's unfair for you to mark this as a duplicate!  This is file I/O, but your link is to a question about networking.  File I/O is dealt with differently than networking in node.js.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Both fire events only asynchronously, which prevents any race conditions with synchronous subscriptions, even if their underlying implementation is different.